# Convert rows as column using python

Tags: python

i have file.txt with below content.

```
jega
divya
ramya
```

i need output file like below

```
jega divya ramya
```

Could anyone help me on this with python code?

Comment: Replace `\n`s with `' '`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you exactly want to do. Below code get *input.txt* as input file and create *output.txt*

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    rows = f.readlines()

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(' '.join([ele.strip() for ele in rows]))
```